# Sampling an MVar, can I avoid unsafePerformIO?

Tags: haskell, unsafe-perform-io

I have

```
sample :: MVar a -> IO [a]
sample v = do
   a <- takeMVar v
   pure (a:unsafePerformIO (sample v))
```

which appears to be a legitimate use of `unsafePerformIO` to me. But I am very interested to know how to avoid it! Is there a pattern for this use already?

Comment: How is it more unsafe than the readLn action. After all the result is IO [a]

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that this is legitimate use of the Fᴜɴᴄᴛɪᴏɴ ᴛʜᴀᴛ ꜱʜᴀʟʟ ɴᴏᴛ ʙᴇ ɴᴀᴍᴇᴅ. With concurrency in the game, there's all kinds of things that could go wrong if the compiler messes up with referential transparancy assumptions. If `sample` worked really safely, then it would probably be in the library already.

Comment: If you are going to go with the `unsafe` route, you should at least use `unsafeInterleaveIO` here, which is the intended method of implementing lazy IO. Note that `getChanContents` itself uses `unsafeInterleaveIO` in order to lazily produce the entire contents of the Chan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement a similar function using a thread, a `Chan` and [`getChanContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html#v:getChanContents):

```
sample :: MVar a -> IO [a]
sample v = do
   c <- newChan
   forkIO $ forever $ takeMVar v >>= writeChan c
   getChanContents c
```

The thread/`getChanContents` approach is slightly better, since at least you can rely on the `MVar` being continuously taken. Instead, the `unsafePerformIO` approach will run `takeMVar` at impredictable points, making the `putMVar`s blocking in a similarly impredictable way. Of course, the `getChanContents` approach will buffer all the data, possibly requiring more memory.

However, both approaches are essentially similar to lazy IO, which is best to be avoided, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with this, in all aspects.

Comment: could you explain in which way `getChanContents` is more predictable than using `unsafePerformIO`. I guess with other approaches than lazy IO you refer to things like [`pipes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) or [`conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit).

Comment: @epsilonhalbe One (admittedly non-technical) advantage of `getChanContents` over manually using `unsafePerformIO`: it is maintained by experts in both GHC and concurrency; it is also more widely used than a homebrew solution and therefore more likely to be the scrutinee if/when a bug in its implementation creeps in.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe It's the `forever` loops that makes that approach more predictable, not the `getChanContents`. Even if no one demands elements in the returned list, `forever` will continuously take the MVar and buffer the read values in the channel. So, each `putMVar v` used elsewhere is guaranteed to always eventually find `v` empty.